# VB.NET - Created Class, Working with WriteOnly property but its not replacing variable value

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

After program execution, the extension that the FileStream uses is the default one provided in the Class header instead of the one i specified via the "set property".

How come it never changed?

*Form1.vb Code*

```
Option Strict On

    Imports S3_BalanceBook_Dayan.Wallet

    Public Class Form1
        Dim myWallet As New Wallet(DataGridView1, DateTimePicker1)

        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


            'Make default selection when program starts.
            optCheck.Checked = True
            myWallet.StatementsFileName = "statements.dat"
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {"12/21/1986", "Test", "44554", "44.22", "45.12"})




        End Sub

        Private Sub cmdAddTransaction_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdAddTransaction.Click
            If optCheck.Checked Then
                lblAvailableFunds.Text = FormatCurrency(myWallet.Check(CInt(Trim(txtCheck.Text)), _
                                                                       CDec(Trim(txtMoney.Text))))
            End If
        End Sub



        Private Sub optDeposit_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles optDeposit.CheckedChanged
            'Disable un-needed fields when Deposit Radio button is selected!
            txtCheck.Enabled = False
            txtMoney.Enabled = False
            txtDeposit.Enabled = True
            txtFee.Enabled = False
            txtDescription.Enabled = True
        End Sub
        Private Sub optCheck_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles optCheck.CheckedChanged
            'Disable un-needed fields when Check Radio button is selected!
            txtCheck.Enabled = True
            txtMoney.Enabled = True
            txtDeposit.Enabled = False
            txtFee.Enabled = False
            txtDescription.Enabled = True

        End Sub
        Private Sub optServiceFee_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles optServiceFee.CheckedChanged
            'Disable un-needed fields when Fee Radio button is selected!
            txtCheck.Enabled = False
            txtMoney.Enabled = False
            txtDeposit.Enabled = False
            txtFee.Enabled = True
            txtDescription.Enabled = True

        End Sub


    End Class
```

*Wallet.vb Code*

```
Option Strict On
Imports System
Imports System.IO


Public Class Wallet

    Private lcheckNumber As Integer = Nothing
    Private lcheckmoney As Decimal = Nothing
    Private ldepositAmount As Decimal = Nothing
    Private lfee As Decimal = Nothing

    Private holdInstance As DataGridView
    Private holdDate As DateTimePicker
    Private holdPath As String = "default.txt"
    Private _file As New FileStream(holdPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    Private file As New StreamWriter(_file)

    'Default Constructor
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByRef Data As DataGridView, ByRef StatementDate As DateTimePicker)
        'This constructor takes in references to use in class as private
        holdInstance = Data
        holdDate = StatementDate
    End Sub


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Property allows the change of file path for the statements log.
    ''' </summary>
    Public WriteOnly Property StatementsFileName() As String
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            holdPath = Value
        End Set
    End Property


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Enter Deposit amount as Decimal, returns remainding account balance as Decimal.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Function Deposit(ByVal Amount As Decimal) As Decimal

        Return 0D
    End Function
    'Function Check - Deduct the amount and returns current balance.
    Public Function Check(ByVal CheckNumber As Integer, ByVal CheckAmount As Decimal) As Decimal
        Try

            file.WriteLine(CheckNumber & " - " & CheckAmount)

        Catch e As IOException
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString)
        End Try

        Return 0D
    End Function
    'Function Fee - Deduct the fee from balance and returns current balance.
    Public Function Fee(ByVal FeeAmount As Decimal) As Decimal

        Return 0D
    End Function



End Class
```

Comment: Who knows? Maybe at some point `myWallet` is replaced with a fresh instance, or `Save` (which you haven't shown) is called on a different instance. Or maybe `Save` has `default.txt` hard coded inside it. Maybe `Save` is called *before* `Form1_Load` runs. Plenty of possible issues, but we can't tell you which because you haven't shown us those pieces of code.

Comment: (Maybe `Save` uses some other object for the actual saving, and that object was initialized in the `Wallet` constructor)

Comment: Its a simple project with only one instance of Wallet. There is no where else where holdFile is being manipulated. This is what confuses me. Only place where we refer to holdFile is on the set property and header declaration of holdFile. Other than that, the next declaration is that of FileStream which takes in holdFile as parametwe.

Comment: I concur with @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I think that another instance is at work here. You can check adding a Shared InstanceID = 0 in header of wallet, increment by 1 in the constructor and check in the Save method if the InstanceID is 1

Comment: Wherever the problem is, it doesn't *appear* to be in the code you've posted so far.

Comment: You need to show the Saving code because what you have posted so far will not exhibit the error you described.

Comment: Thank you guys, sorry for not posting the full code! :) I went ahead and edited the post to include everything. Thanks again!!

Comment: You know you're doing some odd things in your code? You've got module level stream variables left open and you're passing variables `ByRef` when it's not necessary. They may not be bugs but they certainly are a petri dish where bugs can grow...

Comment: Hi Enigmativity, thanks for the feedback I was not aware of this. When you refer to "module level stream variables left open" are you referring to the Check() method where i use file.writeline()?? Also, how come passing by ref via the new constructor is  not necessary? The purpose of this was to ensure I get the address of that object, those objects will be used by to do all calculations and then the method will return an account balance that will be formatted as currency on a label. I Just want bit more details as to why ByRef is not good here, I thought I was making a good choice ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup - it's here that the problem is:

```
Private holdPath As String = "default.txt"
Private _file As New FileStream(holdPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
Private file As New StreamWriter(_file)
```

That will initialize `_file` with the value of `holdPath`, *at the point at which the `Wallet` instance is created*. Instead of having `_file` and `file` as member fields, why not make them local variables inside `Check`? That way, when they're constructed, they'll use the value of `holdPath`, as it is at that time.

---

You should also, probably, put them inside `Using` statements, or otherwise ensure that they're closed at a suitable point - otherwise, the contents you write to the file may not appear until your program is closed.

---

So, we'd have:

```
Public Function Check(ByVal CheckNumber As Integer, ByVal CheckAmount As Decimal) As Decimal
    Try
        Using _file As New FileStream(holdPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
            Using file As New StreamWriter(_file)
                file.WriteLine(CheckNumber & " - " & CheckAmount)
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch e As IOException
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString)
    End Try

    Return 0D
End Function
```